# How do I get the LuaTex fonts to show up?

Tags: fonts, luatex, lyx

According to [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LuaTeX) page on the LyX wiki, I should be able to use a LuaTex font by clicking Document→Settings→Fonts→Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX), but when I do this, my PDF still compiles with the default font. Here is what this looks like for me in LyX (Arial Narrow is the font I would like to use):

[image]

I'm wondering whether it may have to do with the settings I have in my preamble. Specifically, I am using the `fontspec`, `polyglossia`, and `biblatex` packages.

Comment: I know nothing about lyx but it looks like you selected Arial Narrow for sans serif `\sffamily` and have not changed the default font

Answer (score 1):

Write into your preamble

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

or choose also Arial for the roman font, which is always the font at
the beginning of a document, if not redefined.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you downloaded the ARM version of LyX, instead of the Intel version? I had problems with fonts, too, on my M1 ARM MacBook Air. Download the Intel (*LyX-2.4.0-beta2+qt5-x86_64-cocoa.dmg*) version on the [Development Page](https://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.4/) and see if that helps.